# Derivative of trace involving Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields, hadamard-product

Let us assume that $A, S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$. I am trying to differentiate the following expression: $$\Phi(U,V)=\mathrm{trace}\left((S\circ A)(S^T\circ(VU^T))\right),$$
with respect to $U$ and $V$, respectively, i.e.:
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial U}\quad and\quad \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial V}.$$

in which $\mathrm{trace}(\cdot)$ is the trace of a matrix, and $\circ$ is the Hadamard product.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think $VU^T$ is defined. It's probably a typo.

Comment: @Jacky Chong, Sorry, the size of V was corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\T{\operatorname{Tr}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$For
typing convenience, let's define the matrix variable
$$B=S\circ S\circ A$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \T(A^TB) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
The properties of the trace allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$
Further, the Frobenius and Hadamard products commute
$$A:(B\circ C) = (A\circ B):C$$
Write the cost function using the above notation, then calculate its differential and gradients.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (S\circ A):\big(S\circ UV^T\big) \\&= B:UV^T \\
d\phi &= B:\big(dU\,V^T+U\,dV^T\big) \\&= BV:dU \;+\; B^TU:dV \\
\p{\phi}{U} &= BV \qquad\quad \p{\phi}{V} = B^TU \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.